# How do I successfully upgrade my bootstrap from v4.1 to 4.4? Site Crashed

Tags: bootstrap-4

I was building a site with bootstrap v4.1 and realized that I was not able to access new features such as breakpoints for classes and gradients. I went to getbootstrap.com and grabbed the newest CDN so I could use the new features. Problem is the site will not work at all now. I feel like I have not done it right. The example of the crashed site can be viewed at http://www.ellencavallo.com/newsite/CandlewoodLakeLifestyle/template.html

A previous working version using v4.1 can be found at http://www.ellencavallo.com/newsite/CandlewoodLakeLifestyle

this is exactly what i added to my header
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">`

this is directly above closing body tag.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Can someone please tell me how to get bootstrap v4.4 correctly working?

Comment: Take a look at the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools as you're loading the "crashed" site. You're getting 403 Forbidden errors when the browser tries to load the bootstrap related files. Do you need to register your site with this CDN or something? Maybe try another CDN instead, if that one doesn't work. Please learn to use your Developer Tools to debug your site...it will save you hours of pain. If you do, you'll also notice that you appear to be trying to load bootstrap.min.js twice into the same page, which is certainly unnecessary.

Comment: I just updated CDN and it is working. Thank you!

Comment: Well actually I just noted you're trying to load 4.4.1, which was literally only released by Bootstrap today! (See https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/11/28/bootstrap-4-4-1/). So probably the CDN people have locked it down while they test it out a bit and so on. Maybe stick to 4.4.0, it's a bit less raw! E.g. `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js` works perfectly well as of this moment. If you desperately require 4.4.1 due to the fixes it provides, you might just have to be patient for a few days.

Comment: i just used 4.3 and it is working. Thanks alot.